# Understanding apyori's output

Tags: python, apriori

I'm well familiar with the apriori algorithm, and the meaning of support/confidence/lift.

I'm currently using the [apyori](https://github.com/ymoch/apyori) apriori implementation, and I'm not sure I understand the **output** of an `apyori.apriori()` call.

It comes out like this

```
> RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'item1', 'item2'}),
> support=0.15365410803449842,
> ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'item1'}),
> items_add=frozenset({'item2'}), confidence=0.6203420891875382,
> lift=2.2233410344037092),
> OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'item2'}),
> items_add=frozenset({'item1'}), confidence=0.5507049891540131,
> lift=2.2233410344037097)])
```

What is the rule? There are multiple support/confidence/lift, what each one denotes?

I'd appreciate a dictionary style explanation of each part of the output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The RelationRecord reflects a subset of items, while ordered_statistics is a list of OrderedStatistics, which reflect the rules. Each OrderedStatistics' items_base is the antecedent and the items_add is the consequent. The support is stored in the RelationRecord, since it's the same for the contained rules.

In your example:

item1 -> item2 with 0.62 confidence and 2.2233410344037092x lift

item2 -> item1 with 0.55 confidence and 2.2233410344037097x lift

Both have support=0.15365410803449842.

For what it's worth, I ended up switching to using [PyFIM](http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html) for relative feature richness and other bundled algorithms (e.g. fp-growth).

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and see if my answer was helpful/you continued using apyori. If you found this helpful, please select it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: do you know if the `rules` returned from the algorithm is by default sorted in some order? `rules = apriori(transactions, min_support = 0.003, min_confidence = 0.2, min_lift = 3, min_length = 2)`

Comment: Thanks for this. I really wish `apyori` had a proper documentation.

Comment: @Jay note that there's no keyword arg `min_length`.

Comment: @timegeb - Just whipped these unofficial docs together. Hope they help! http://www.zaxrosenberg.com/unofficial-apyori-documentation/

Comment: By the way, how do I interpret a rule of the type: `frozenset({}) -> fronzenset({item})` What does an empty frozenset mean?